# numpy subclass will not accept arguments to __new__ from pythonically inheriting class

Tags: python, inheritance, numpy, attributeerror, default-arguments

I've created a subclass of ndarray called "Parray" which takes two arguments: p, and dimensionality. It works fine on its own. Now, I want to create a class called SirPlotsAlot, which inherits Parray without all the fancy **new** and **array_finalize** etc.

```
import numpy as np

class Parray(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(self, p = Parameters(), dimensionality = 2):

        print "Initializing Parray with initial dimensionality %s..." % dimensionality

        self.p = p # store the parameters

        if dimensionality == 2:
            shape = (p.nx, p.ny)
            self.pshape = shape
        elif dimensionality == 3:
            shape=(p.nx, p.ny, p.nx)
            self.pshape = shape
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError, "dimensionality must be 2 or 3"

        # ...Set other variables (ellided)

        subarr = np.ndarray.__new__(self, shape, dtype, buffer, offset, strides, order)
        subarr[::] = np.zeros(self.pshape) # initialize to zero
        return subarr
...

class SirPlotsAlot(Parray):
    def __init__(self, p = Parameters(), dimensions = 3):
        super(SirPlotsAlot, self).__new__(p, dimensions)     # (1)
```

Objects in my program share sets of parameters by passing an object p = Parameters() back and forth.

Now, when I type (the file is auxiliary.py):

```
import auxiliary
from parameters import Parameters
p = Parameters()
s = auxiliary.SirPlotsAlot(p, 3)
```

expecting to get a nice "Initializing Parray with initial dimensionality 3", I get "2", instead. BUT if I type:

```
import auxiliary
s = auxiliary.SirPlotsAlot()
```

I get

```
---> 67             shape = (p.nx, p.ny)
"AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'nx'"
```

It thinks "p" is an int, which it is not. I can get lots of weird seemingly unrelated errors if I play around with it. The int it thinks it is is "2". I'm completely lost.

I've tried with and without the # (1) comment (the super call).

Other errors from playing around include "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'p'",  "TypeError: **new**() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)", "ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack" (I replaced **new**'s arguments with *args, something I don't understand very well).

Comment: If Python thinks `p` is an int, it's probably correct. Use `pdb` to put a breakpoint at that line and see what you have. Do a stack trace to see how you got there. Note very carefully if the files mentioned in the trace are the ones you *think* should be there. More than one person has gotten messed up when the library paths were slightly wrong.

Comment: One issue which hints that there might be a problem elsewhere in your code is that the "p=Parameters()" call in the `__init__` probably doesn't do what you think it does.  It doesn't make a new Parameters instance whenever `Parray.__new__` is called: instead, it makes *one*, when the function is first declared.  IOW, each Parray shares a Parameter instance when not passed one, which seems unlikely to have been your intention.  [I don't see how this can be the problem here, but it might cause problems elsewhere.]

Comment: Your combined use of `__new__()` and `__init__()` is... unorthodox, to say the least. Why are you using `__new__()` on your Parray class again? That looks like a plain old `__init__()` method to me; there's no reason to write it as `__new__()`. And why are you storing attributes on the class? (In `__new__()` the first parameter is a reference to the class, not to an instance, because there isn't an instance.)

Comment: @DSM: Good catch; I wasn't even looking at that, but this is one of those subtle bugs that can really trip up Python newbies (and sometimes oldbies, too).

Comment: Just to make it clear, `__new__` is a class method so the first argument to `__new__` isn't an instance (ie self) it is a class. It's good to use something like `def __new__(cls, ...` to remind yourself, and anyone else reading the code, that your operating on a class not an instance. Looks like you might be able to drop new in favor of init, but it's a good thing to know for the future.

Comment: @DSM, Thank you! That is great to know. And thank you everyone else. I am using `__new__()` because of the ndarray documentation, like keflavich linked to. I read these comments and tried to as much functionality as possible into `__init__()`, but I need `__new__` so `ndarray.view(Parray)` works, and thus need the d'ty d size (`p.nx`) in that same call to ndarray (subarr = ...). I tried using a dummy size (1,1,1) and multiplying and reshaping the array in `__init__`. It didn't work, but there's room for more exploration. I'll do what Peter Rowell suggested after I implement some math stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been ten years and I long left the project, but I resolved this issue by creating helper functions to create new classes and set them up. In the code example below, see the definitions at the bottom of the file. I imported and used those.

Props to Matthew Schinckel to pointing out that `__new__` should have already been called by the time `__init__` runs, and to everyone else for their thoughts.

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Era's Plotting Functionality. This module exports SirPlotsAlot and company:
    
class SirPlotsAlot: Array with 2D, 3D, animated plotting capability, and a pyrism Parameteres object.

def NewSirPlotsAlot(p, dimensionality): returns SirPlotsAlot, but doesn't need explicit parameters

def returns_SirPlotsAlot: decorator force ndarray-returning function to return SirPlotsAlot instead.

Created on Thu Jul 12 18:46:15 2012
@author: Era
"""

# SirPlotsAlot
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
import numpy as np
import scipy as scipy
import logging

lprint = logging.getLogger('pyrism')



class SirPlotsAlot(np.ndarray):
    """
    An array with 2D, 3D, animated plotting capability, and a pyrism Parameters object.

    Inherits: numpy's ndarray

    Input:    
        dimensionality: An int. The dimensions of the ndarray. Can be changed later.
        p:  A Parameters object.

    """

    # class variables
    currentSlice = 0    # for _updateSlice and animated plots

    
    def __new__(cls, shape):
        """
        Creates a new SirPlotsAlot for us to use.

        SirPlotsAlot inherits ndarray. ndarray is written in C, and needs an extra\
        method called __new__ to help it.
        
        Args:
            shape: A tuple of ints. The shape of the underlying ndarray.
            
        Returns:
            an ndarray
            
        Author / Date:
            Erasmus Alcarin   /   January 23rd, 2012
            Erasmus Alcarin   /      July 13th, 2012
            
        """

       
        ### Specify the exact parameters of the array this class implements
        dtype=float         # dtype: data type. Optional
                                # Any object can be interpreted as
                                # a numpy datatype
        buffer=None         # buffer: object exposing buffer interface. Optional
                                # Used to fill array with data
        offset=0            # offset: int. Optional.
                                # offset of array in data buffer
        strides=None        # strides : tuple of ints. Optional
                                # Strides of data in memory
        order=None          # order : {'C', 'F'}. Optional
                                # Row-major or column-major order.
        
        # Instantiate new ndarray (this class). Temporarily called sub_array.
        subarr = np.ndarray.__new__(cls,   # cls is crucial.
                                            # it creates a ndarray that
                                            # is of type THIS CLASS
                                            # instead of type ndarray
                shape, dtype, buffer, offset, strides, order)
        
        # Return the successfully created instance for this class to use!
        return subarr


    def __init__(self, shape):
        """Says hello!

        Args:
            shape: A tuple of ints. The shape of the underlying ndarray.

        Returns:
            None

        Author:
            Erasmus Alcarin   /   January 23rd, 2012
            Erasmus Alcarin   /      July 13th, 2012

        """
        lprint.debug("Ah, kind sir! Thy bidding be done!")


    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        """Allow inheritance of ndarray's unary(?) operations.

        Purpose:  ndarray has a lot of functions which let you interact
                  with it (all its awesome features, specifically views
                  and so-called "new-from-template": that is, slices).
                  This function tells python that our class also gets
                  to use all of those nifty "unary" features!

        Args:
            obj: Another object. For example, this function is called if we type
                myArr = myIntensityMap[1:]
                (myArr is obj, and myIntensityMap is self)

        Returns:
            None

        Author / Date:
            Erasmus Alcarin   /   January 23rd, 2012

        """
        if obj is None: return
        

    def __array_wrap__(self, out_arr, context=None):
        """Allow inheritance of ndarray's binary(?) operations.

        Purpose:  ndarray has a lot of functions which let you interact
                  with it (all its awesome features, specifically array
                  adding, multiplying, etc.). This function tells python
                  to use all of those nifty "binary" features!

        Args:
            out_arr: What is returned in the operation which is being
                performed.
            context: A parameter which _array_wrap__ is specified to take. (optional)
                If you know, update me!

        Returns:
            See ndarray.__array_wrap___()

        Author / Date:
            Erasmus Alcarin   /   January 23rd, 2012

        """
        # Call ndarray's __array_wrap__ method.
        return np.ndarray.__array_wrap__(self, out_arr, context).view(type(self))


    def _enforceXD(self, X):
        """
        a helper function returning true if this
        SirPlotsAlot has dimensionality X, otherwise
        raising a ValueError.

        Args:
            X: An int. The underlying ndarray dimensionality being tested for.

        Returns:
            True if this array has dimensionality X.
            ValueError is raised otherwise.

        """
        if self.shape.__len__() == X:
            return True
        else:
            raise ValueError, "A %sD array was required. A %sD array was supplied." % (X, self.shape.__len__())


    def _checkXD(self, X):
        """
        a helper function returning true if this
        SirPlotsAlot has dimensionality X, otherwise
        raising a ValueError.

        Args:
            X: An int. The underlying ndarray dimensionality being tested for.

        Returns:
            True if this array has dimensionality X.
            False otherwise.

        """
        if self.shape.__len__() == X:
            return True
        else:
            return False


    def _checkLabelInfo(self, label = None):
        """
        a helper utility function to decide which
        of the accepted formats for plot label the user
        has specified.

        Args:
            label: The user's input (Valid formats are String, Tuple)

        Returns:
            Nothing
        
        """
        if len(label) >= 1 and type(label[0]) == str:
            pyplot.title(label[0])
        if len(label) >= 2 and type(label[1]) == str:
            pyplot.xlabel(label[1])
        if len(label) >= 3 and type(label[2]) == str:
            pyplot.ylabel(label[2])
        if len(label) >= 4 and type(label[3]) == str:
            pyplot.zlabel(label[3])
    
    
    def _add_labels(self, label = None, caller_label = 'none'):
        """
        A utility function to quickly add labels to
        any of the graphing utilities embedded in
        SirPlotsAlot.

        Args:
            label: (Str, Tuple) The label being supplied by the user.
            caller_label: A string. Each plotting function has its own
                axes to label. This identifies the plotting function.

        Returns:
            Nothing

        """
        if label == None:
            raise ValueError, "_add_labels violated"
        else:
            lprint.debug("going on to labelling")

        if type(label) == str:
            pyplot.title(label)
        elif type(label) == tuple:
            self._checkLabelInfo(label)
        
        elif hasattr(self, 'caller_label'):
            label = getattr(self, caller_label)
            
            if type(label) == str:
                pyplot.title(label)
            elif type(label) == tuple:
                self._checkLabelInfo(label)
        
        else:
            print getattr(self, caller_label)
            raise ValueError, "_add_labels requires string or tuple of strings"
            

    def _updateSlice(self):
        """
        a helper function for animate2D(), this controls the
        progression (speed, sampling) of the animation by
        returning the next image to be presented in the animation.

        Args:
            None

        Returns:
            2D slice of this array.

        """
        if self._enforceXD(3):
            self.currentSlice += 1
        
            return self[self.currentSlice]


    def plot1D(self, label = None):
        """
        Plot 1-axis SirPlotsAlot in 2D, plotting array contents as y (up).

        Args:
            label: String or tuple labelling the plot.

        Returns:
            Nothing

        """
        if self._enforceXD(1):
            pyplot.figure()
            
            # self._add_labels(label, 'plot1D_label')
            
            pyplot.plot(self)
             
            pyplot.show()


    def plot2D(self, label = None):
        """
        Plot 2-axis SirPlotsAlot in 2D, plotting array contents as color.

        Args:
            label: String or tuple labelling the plot.

        Returns:
            Nothing

        """
        if self._enforceXD(2):
            # Do not produce huge output
            #lprint.debug("We're plotting this up:\n%s" % self)
            lprint.debug("We're plotting you some goodies!")

            fig = pyplot.figure()
            if type(label) == str:      # if label is supplied, apply it.
                pyplot.title(label)
            elif hasattr(self, 'plot2D_label'):
                pyplot.title(self.plot2D_label)

            plot = pyplot.imshow(self)
            
            fig.colorbar(plot)
            #colorbar.ax.set_yticklabels(["%.2f" % self.min(), '0', "%.2f" % self.max()])

            pyplot.gca().invert_yaxis()

            pyplot.xlabel('x')
            pyplot.ylabel('y')

            pyplot.show()


    def save_plot2D(self, file = None, label = None, cbar_ticks = None):
        """
        Saves plot of 2-axis SirPlotsAlot in 2D, plotting array contents as color,
        in .png format.

        Args:
            file: A string. The filename to save to. Default: ``output``
            label: String or tuple labelling the plot.
            cbar_ticks: Colorbar ticks for plot. Default: auto.

        Returns:
            Nothing

        """
        if self._enforceXD(2):
            # Do not produce huge output
            #lprint.debug("We're plotting this up:\n%s" % self)
            lprint.debug("We're plotting you some goodies!")

            fig = pyplot.figure()
            if label is not None:
                self._add_labels(label, 'plot2D_label')

            plot = pyplot.imshow(self)
            
            if cbar_ticks == None:
                fig.colorbar(plot)
            else:
                cbar = fig.colorbar(plot, ticks=cbar_ticks) # Numbers
                cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(map(str, cbar_ticks))   # Label

            pyplot.gca().invert_yaxis()

            if file == None:
                file = 'output'
            pyplot.savefig(file)


    # nice!
    def plot3D(self, label = None):
        """
        Plots 2-axis SirPlotsAlot in 3D, plotting array contents as 3rd dimension (up).

        Args:
            label: String or tuple labelling the plot.

        Returns:
            Nothing

        """
        if self._enforceXD(2):
            # Do not produce huge output
            #lprint.debug("We're plotting this up:\n%s" % self)
            lprint.debug("We're plotting you some goodies!")

            # make grid from min to max with interval nx
            x = scipy.linspace(0, self.shape[1], self.shape[1])
            y = scipy.linspace(0, self.shape[0], self.shape[0])
            [x, y] = scipy.meshgrid(x, y)       # this is the same as make_2d

            fig = pyplot.figure()
            if type(label) == str:      # if label is supplied, apply it.
                pyplot.title(label)
            elif hasattr(self, 'plot3D_label'):
                pyplot.title(self.plot3D_label)

            ax = Axes3D(fig)                    # make a 3D axis
            ax.plot_surface(x, y, self)

            pyplot.xlabel('x')
            pyplot.ylabel('y')

            pyplot.show()


    def plot3D_2(self, label = None):
        """
        Plots 2-axis SirPlotsAlot in 3D, plotting array contents as 3rd dimension (up),
        with contours projected onto each 2D cross-section of the 3D plot.

        Args:
            label: String or tuple labelling the plot.

        Returns:
            Nothing

        """
        if self._enforceXD(2):
            # Do not produce huge output
            #lprint.debug("We're plotting this up:\n%s" % self)
            lprint.debug("We're plotting you some goodies!")

            # make grid from min to max with interval nx
            x = scipy.linspace(0, self.shape[1], self.shape[1])
            y = scipy.linspace(0, self.shape[0], self.shape[0])
            [x, y] = scipy.meshgrid(x, y)

            fig = pyplot.figure()
            if type(label) == str:
                pyplot.title(label)
            elif hasattr(self, 'plot3D_2_label'):
                pyplot.title(self.plot3D_2_label)

            ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

            ax.plot_surface(x, y, self, rstride=8, cstride=8, alpha=0.3)
            ax.contour(x, y, self, zdir='z', offset=self.min())
            ax.contour(x, y, self, zdir='x', offset=0)
            ax.contour(x, y, self, zdir='y', offset=self.shape[0])

            ax.set_xlabel('x')
            ax.set_xlim(0, self.shape[1])
            ax.set_ylabel('y')
            ax.set_ylim(0, self.shape[0])
            ax.set_zlabel('z')
            ax.set_zlim(self.min(), self.max())

            pyplot.show()

        # the following is probably deprecated code for the above.
        '''if self._enforceXD(2):
            print "We're plotting this up:\n%s" % self

            # make grid from min to max with interval nx
            x = y = scipy.linspace(self.min(), self.max(), self.shape[0])
            [x, y] = scipy.meshgrid(x, y)       # this is the same as make_2d

            fig = pyplot.figure()
            if type(label) == str:      # if label is supplied, apply it.
                pyplot.title(label)
            elif hasattr(self, 'plot3D_label'):
                pyplot.title(self.plot3D_label)

            ax = Axes3D(fig)                    # make a 3D axis
            ax.plot_surface(x, y, self)

            pyplot.show()
        '''


    def aniPlot2D(self):
        """
        Generate successive 2D color plots using color for the data. Then play these
        plots in series, creating an animation. Requires 3D SirPlotsAlot.

        Args:
            None

        Returns:
            Nothing

        """
        self.tplot = 0

        fig = pyplot.figure()

        #x = np.arange(0, self.shape[1])
        #y = np.arange(0, self.shape[0]).reshape(-1,1)

        ims = []
        imsappend = ims.append      # optimization
        for t in np.arange(self.shape[1]):
            imsappend((pyplot.imshow(self[t]),))

        animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, interval=50, repeat_delay=3000, blit=True)

        pyplot.show()



def NewSirPlotsAlot(shape = (512, 512)):
    """
    Returns instance of SirPlotsAlot explicitly initiallized to all zeros;
    arguments may be left unspecified.

    Args:
        shape: A tuple of ints. The shape of the underlying ndarray.

    Returns:
        SirPlotsAlot

    Author / Date:
        Erasmus Alcarin   /   July 13, 2012

    """
    s = SirPlotsAlot(shape)
    s[:] = np.zeros(s.shape)

    lprint.info("SirPlotsAlot has been populated with zeros.")

    return s


# Aliases for NewSirPlotsAlot
splot = NewSirPlotsAlot


def NewPsirPlotsAlot(dimensionality = 3, p = None):
    """
    Returns instance of SirPlotsAlot explicitly initiallized to all zeros;
    arguments may be left unspecified.

    Args:
        dimensionality: An int. Number of dimensions for array. (optional)
        p: A Parameters object. Simulation parameters. (optional)

    Returns:
        SirPlotsAlot

    Author / Date:
        Erasmus Alcarin   /   July 13, 2012

    """
    lprint.debug("Initializing SirPlotsAlot with initial dimensionality %s..." % dimensionality)
    # NewSirPlotsAlot()
    try:
        import pyrism.parameters as par
    except:
        import sys
        lprint.error("Use of pyrism as non-package detected. You must remain in the pyrism directory.")
        import parameters as par


    if p == None:
        p = par.Parameters.Instance()

    # extract size from parameters file, assuming size nx, ny
    if dimensionality == 2:
        shape = (p.ny, p.nx)
    elif dimensionality == 3:
        shape = (p.nx, p.ny, p.nx)
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError, "dimensionality must be 2 or 3"
        
    # Make and Get object
    s = SirPlotsAlot(shape)
    s[:] = np.zeros(s.shape)

    lprint.info("SirPlotsAlot has been populated with zeros.")

    return s
        
        
# Aliases for NewPsirPlotsAlot
psplot = NewPsirPlotsAlot


def returns_SirPlotsAlot(fn):
    """
    A decorator that changes an ndarray to a SirPlotsAlot by
    means of the ndarray view function. (Returns SirPlotsAlot)

    """
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        return fn(*args, **kwargs).view(SirPlotsAlot)
    return wrapped


# Aliases for returns_SirPlotsAlot
returns_splot = returns_SirPlotsAlot
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to echo kindall, and say "don't use `__new__`". Your `Parray.__new__` method looks more like an initialisation, and should be using `__init__`, like it's subclass is.

Comment: Are you sure?  I think subclassing `np.ndarray`, you're supposed to use `__new__` and not `__init__` http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html

Comment: That was exactly what I was thinking. That's why I was hoping every subclass of my new ndarray subclass wouldn't have to follow ndarray's rules. One avenue of exploration I'm currently considering is to try treating Parray as an ndarray. As a quick fix, I removed variable default statements in class initialization, and made helper functions: NewSirPlotsAlot(p = Parameters() dimensions=3): return SirPlotsAlot(p, dimensions). Not quite what I want, but it seems to work.

Comment: @keflavich: Good point. I haven't seen much python code that requires `__new__`. What you probably don't want to do is call `__new__` from `__init__`, as it will have already been called.